# Import Google API layer into QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, google

I found this streetlight layer: https://oncorstreetlight.com/api/location/category/18/public/map
and I would like to display it with other layers I have on my PC.
I'm wondering how can I import the data to my QGIS app.

Comment: Looks like city of Dallas has this data in a MapServer Layer https://gis.dallascityhall.com/wwwgis/rest/services/Trn_public/CityOwnedStreetLights/MapServer

Comment: @Mapperz its a very different data set. I think two separate ownerships. The "city" ones in that MapServer layer are Dallas-only, the Oncor ones which I can see in much wider parts of Texas (Waco and beyond...)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the web requests, the streetlight data comes from a POST call to

```
https://api.oncorstreetlight.com/api/location/category/18/public/map
```

with a request containing a bounding box JSON structure:

```
{"boundary":
  {"northEast":{"latitude":32.758741998638406,"longitude":-97.30540172664185},
   "southWest":{"latitude":32.74661495449476,"longitude":-97.33007804957886}}
}
```

and a response JSON like this:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "markers": [
      {
        "key": "1155817",
        "icon": "guardlight",
        "data": {
          "fln": "3819850-3587284",
          "gln": "3819850-3587284"
        },
        "latitude": 32.757149,
        "longitude": -97.328838
      },
      {
        "key": "998397",
        "icon": "guardlight",
        "data": {
          "fln": "3819849-3587125",
          "gln": "3819849-3587125"
        },
        "latitude": 32.756717,
        "longitude": -97.32874
      },
```

This doesn't look like any standard web map format I know of, so I doubt its viewable in QGIS as-is. You either need to write some code to wrap this in a standard web services call, or write a some code to implement a new layer in QGIS that supports this format.

Or find another source of this data that is in a standard format...